# Reversing XML nodes in perl

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I need to reverse the order of children nodes in a parent node.
This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">

<tv source-info-name="BDS" generator-info-name="mc2xml" generator-    info-url="mailto:mc2xml@gmail.com">
<channel id="I2.751784.microsoft.com">
    <display-name>2 1Xtra BBC</display-name>
    <display-name>2</display-name>
    <display-name>1Xtra BBC</display-name>
    <display-name>BBC R1X</display-name>
</channel>
```

The program I feed this xml into only takes the first `display-name` node as the name, which is annoying because then these items are arranger by that number.

So I want the very last node to come up first.

I'm using this script to fetch the `channel` nodes. This is part of code that merges 2 xml's. But I'm stuck from there on:

```
foreach my $chan (  $t2->findnodes( '//channel' ) ) {
    $root->insertAfter( $chan, $last_chan );
    $last_chan = $chan;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example shows a possible solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => <<'END');
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">

<tv source-info-name="BDS" generator-info-name="mc2xml" generator-info-url="mailto:mc2xml@gmail.com">
<channel id="I2.751784.microsoft.com">
    <display-name>2 1Xtra BBC</display-name>
    <display-name>2</display-name>
    <display-name>1Xtra BBC</display-name>
    <display-name>BBC R1X</display-name>
</channel>
</tv>
END

for my $chan ($xml->findnodes("/tv/channel")) {
  $chan->appendChild($_) for reverse $chan->childNodes;
}

print $xml->toString(1);
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM "xmltv.dtd">
<tv source-info-name="BDS" generator-info-name="mc2xml" generator-info-url="mailto:mc2xml@gmail.com">
<channel id="I2.751784.microsoft.com">
<display-name>BBC R1X</display-name>
    <display-name>1Xtra BBC</display-name>
    <display-name>2</display-name>
    <display-name>2 1Xtra BBC</display-name>
    </channel>
</tv>
```

---

**EDIT**

I misunderstood your requirement and thought you wanted the `<display-name>` elements reversing within each `<channel>`. Here is the core of the code to reverse the `<channel>` elements within `<tv>`.

```
my @channels = $xml->find('/tv/channel');
my $tv = $channels[0]->parentNode;
$tv->appendChild($_) for reverse @channels;
```

---

Now I think I was right the first time. Take your pick!

Comment: You were indeed right the first time! And it kind of works. print $t1->toString(1);` does indeed show the right order, but any modifications afterwards still use the same ordering... Do I have to apply the changes in some way?

Comment: The changes are only made to Perl's internal representation of the XML structure. That is why I added `print $xml->toString(1)`: you need to save the modified XML to a file - overwriting the source file or saving to a different one - and use the new version from thereon.

Answer (score 0):

```
for my $channel_node ($root->findnodes('//channel')) {
   for my $child_node (reverse $channel_node->childNodes()) {
      $channel_node->removeChild($child_node);
      $channel_node->appendChild($child_node);
   }
}
```

`appendChild` says it won't work if the node is a already a child of the parent, thus the use of `removeChild`. But testing shows that `removeChild` is not actually needed.

Comment: The DOM is fine with using `appendChild` on an attached node. See my solution. Take out the `removeChild` line from your code and all will be well.

Comment: @Borodin, I already said it works without calling `removeChild` (even though the documentation says you have to use it). Why do you keep repeating the contents of my nodes in comments? And despite the implication, all is well with `replaceChild` there, so might as well follow the documentation.

Comment: My fault - I misread your post. What do you mean by your *nodes*? You are reading far more into my comments than was intended. I am not picking fault with you, but given your reactions I wouldn't have made the comment if I had noticed who had posted the answer.